# Relative Path to load a library?

Tags: c#, path

I got the following compilation folders(simplified) :

```
D:\MySolution\Project1\bin\Debug
D:\MySolution\Project2\bin\Debug
```

My `Project1` has a reference on `Project2` but in the code I have to load a class from Project1 so I used this code that works :

```
var project2ref = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"..\..\..\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll")
                                .CreateInstance("MyNamespace.MyClass");
```

This works in VS but it crashes when I use an install version of my software...
What are the alternatives for the relative path ?

Comment: Why not reference `project2` from `project1` by adding a reference under "references" in your project explorer?

Comment: Most likely your installation folder doesn't have bin\Debug subfolder, does it?

Comment: Project1 already has a ref on Project2 (uses an Interface) so I can't reference Project2 in Project1 (circular dependance)

Comment: When you install your software, where does Project1.dll get placed? Will it always be in the same location regardless of the machine it is installed on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have the dll of project1 into the bin folder of project2 when you'll build the solution. 
So, you can get a reference of the project2.dll by retrieving the assembly path of project1.dll. The below code will be executed inside the project1 and will get the bin path of  the project who will contains both the dll.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: No because Project2 has no reference on Project1 ! And I can't Add this refenrece (see comments on my question)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. If you are facing this issue it is because of a wrong design (you're anyway creating a circular dependance by loading project1 via reflection). Best choice is to move the bit of code you need in project1 in a separate project and reference it as normal dependency.